# How to limit scope of webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack

I'm currently trying to implement typescript into my backend, but since it's quite new to me, I'm trying to figure things out one by one in a test folder, however it seems like webpack is taking all of my files and trying to read them, which gives me errors like:

`Duplicate identifier`, `Module '"xxxx"' has no default export`, `Cannot find name 'Proxy'.`, `Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'xxxx'.`

Here's my config file (still using webpack3 for reasons):

```
"use strict"
const path = require("path")
// const utils = require("./utils")
// const config = require("../config")
var fs = require("fs")
const NodemonPlugin = require("nodemon-webpack-plugin")
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals")

function resolve(dir) 
{
    return path.join(__dirname, "..", dir)
}

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/server/test"),
    entry: "./test.ts",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/server/test"),
        filename: "bundle.js",
    },
    plugins: [
        // new NodemonPlugin(),
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js",".ts", ".tsx"],
        alias: {
            "@": resolve("src"),
            "#": resolve("src/server")
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                include: [resolve("src"), resolve("test")]
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: "ts-loader",
            },
        ]
    },
    externals: [
        nodeExternals()
    ],
    target: "node"
}
```

Comment: What is inside your `./test.ts file` ?

Comment: @Arseniy-II it really shouldn't matter... all it has is one import that's getting one variable from another file in the same folder.

Comment: Ok, I can see no problems with webpack then. I can only suggest you to try change `test.ts` to `test.js` to check is it the `ts-loader` bug.